# Dynamically appending symbol to drop down option

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a dropdown on my page that I'd like to dynamically append a check mark next to each option if certain circumstances are met.  When I have tried the following:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let cl of classes; trackBy id">{{cl.label}}<span class="fa fa-check"></span></option>
  </select>
```

This did not work.  Nothing was appended onto the option. I have even tried a regular character:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let cl of classes; trackBy id">{{cl.label}}<span>X</span></option>
  </select>
```

To no avail.  Even though that particular request was a customer requirement, I attempted the following to provide an alternate solution:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let cl of classes; trackBy id" [ngClass]="{'is-active':cl.selectedStudent=true}">{{cl.label}}</option>
  </select>

.is-active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

It would highlight the option yellow.  This didn't work either.  Then I finally tried just to get a drop down option to highlight with inline styling:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let cl of classes; trackBy id" style="background:yellow;">{{cl.label}}</option>
  </select>
```

This didn't work either.  No matter what I did, I was unable to provide any sort of styling to the dropdown.  Is there something that I am missing or are you unable to style drop down options?  I am using Chrome on MacOS.

Comment: i can't help you if you're trying to go about it using angular, but for jquery it would something like $('option').on('click', function(){ // code here });

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use innerHtml tags inside of `<options>` tag. But solution with alternative color should work. In your particular example, you have typo (1 equals sign), but it highlights only option itself (when options list is expanded) not selected value. You may want to use JS implementation of selectbox. Look for primeNg or ngx-bootstrap as example. But simpliest option is:

```
<option>{{cl.label + (cl.selectedStudent == true ? ' &#9745;' : '')}}</option>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp

Comment: While that works (thank you) on initial load, it will not update when a checkbox (student) is selected for that class.  Do the drop down options get updated if the model changes?  Also, the checkmark has to be green (another customer requirement).  I tried a bit of primeNG (which we have integrated into the project already) and while I can get far and pretty much everything I want, I can't get the checkmarks to conditionally show per class.  I show them with a :after pseudo selector, but they would need to show based on the selectedStudent var.

Comment: Please provide full code, as statement ` when a checkbox (student) is selected for that class` is not clear for me. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, this drop down in question selects a class (in a school).  When a class is selected, the list of students is shown in a grid below the drop down with a checkbox next to each students name.  The ngFor for that isn't really relevant to this issue, but if you'd like to see that code, I can provide.  If a user selects a student in the class, a checkmark is to appear next to the classes name in the drop down.

Comment: Ok, your data structure is: `[{label: "cl1", students: [{label: "st1-1", selectedStudent: false"},{label: "st1-2", selectedStudent: false}]}, {label: "cl2", students: [{label: "st2-1", selectedStudent: false}, {label: "st2-2", selectedStudent: false}]}]`. You iterate over classes, than iterate over students in selected class. If at least one student is selected for class (`selectedStudent: true`) - parent class needs to be highlighted?

Comment: My data structure looks like:  [{
 "name": "Period 5 Advanced Algebra",
 "id": "ABCD4321",
        "selectedStudent": false,
 "studentCount": 19,
 "students": [{
  "name": "Bernard Sampson Sanders",
  "id": "10"
 }, {
  "name": "Johnny Appleseed",
  "id": "11"
 }, {
  "name": "Johnny Appleseed",
  "id": "12"
 }]
}].  When a student is selected for that class, that selectedStudent flag is set.  If all students in that class are not selected, its reverted.  The checkmark should be bound to that flag for that class.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your option I would use `<span *ngIf="cl.selectedStudent == true" class="fa fa-check"></span>` like:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let cl of classes; trackBy id">{{cl.label}}<span *ngIf="cl.selectedStudent == true" class="fa fa-check"></span></option>
  </select>
```

I'd also ask myself if using trackBy is really necessary